# Check number of zeros elements 1D vector in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am using 1D vector in C++ such as

```
std::vector<int> A;
```

Have any way to check or count the number of zeros element in A using C++. For example

```
   A[0]=3;
   A[1]=0;
   A[2]=2;
   A[3]=0;
```

Then number of zeros element in A is 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple iteration over the vector, increasing the count everytime a zero element is encountered seems fine.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
  {
    if (A[i] == 0)
      count++;
  }
return count;
```

You can also use the `count` function.

```
int ans = count(A.begin(), A.end(), 0);
```

Comment: Is it other way in vector class? Scan all elements look slow

Comment: @user8264: Since a vector does not contain any information about the elements in it, you need to atleast visit every element once to check for zeros. I don't think there is a faster way.

Comment: At some level you'll have to look at all of the elements in the vector if their values are random. Now if the values relate to each other in some way you can start making clever shortcuts. Say for instance the vector is sorted... well then you can cut down on the amount of work you need to do.

Comment: Also, if the vector is large enough (read: REALLY large) you can use openmp to multi-thread this comparison. But if the vector is too small, the overhead of setting up the threads will outweigh the gain of multi-threading.

Comment: Straight away use std::count(first_iterator, last_iterator, element_to_count)

Comment: @therainmaker sorry, let me rephrase that. Use std:::count() (as it is already provided by 'std' namespace); instead of looping in vector to check for elements.